# Python: range function for decimal numbers

Tags: python, range, decimal

Is there any range() function in python for float numbers
for example

```
a=0.6

if a in range(0,1):
    a=3
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: Why not just use `if 0 <= a < 1: a = 3` ?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading correctly, you want to test if a number is between two other numbers, so use:

```
a = 0.6
if 0 <= a < 1: # change to `<= 1` to be inclusive
   a = 3
```

You don't need to generate a range and do membership testing - unless you have a discrete set of values that your `a` should match - the builtin `range` in Python 3.x can do efficient lookups for `int`s as it can optimise membership testing. If you have a large amount of discrete values in a large range, then you'd be better of doing it mathematically anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the question linked by Begueradj but slightly different (note, floats are not the same as decimals):

```
import decimal

def drange(start, stop, step=decimal.Decimal('1')):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step

print(list(drange(
    decimal.Decimal('1.25'),
    decimal.Decimal('2.34'),
    decimal.Decimal('0.1'),
)))
```

Output:

```
[Decimal('1.25'), Decimal('1.35'), Decimal('1.45'), Decimal('1.55'),
 Decimal('1.65'), Decimal('1.75'), Decimal('1.85'), Decimal('1.95'), 
 Decimal('2.05'), Decimal('2.15'), Decimal('2.25')]
```

Comment: Note that it can't deal with descending ranges, like `drange(10, 0, -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have numpy installed do:

> `>>>`import numpy
>
> `>>>`print np.arange(0,1,0.1)
>
> array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])

if you don't have Numpy installed, definitely go get it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to check whether a is in between two numbers it's better to use:

`0 <=a<=1`

Otherwise , if you do need a list of say 0  to 1 in 0.1 jumps you can use this code to generate it:


`lst = map(lambda x: x/10.0, range(11))`